# Como remover a opção selecionada em múltiplos ComboBoxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Eu tenho vários componentes do tipo `ComboBox` com opções idênticas. O usuário deve selecionar uma delas(Ex.: "Nome"). Como fazer para que quando uma opção for selecionada, em qualquer um `ComboBox`, ela desapareça de todos os `ComboBox`?

Preciso de um banco? Ou um `IList`?

Comment: Parece ser duas dúvidas. A primeira em como salvar o dado do usuário e a outra em como não exibir depois que for selecionado uma vez.

Comment: Tentando me retratar da minha postura pouco amigável no comentário anterior: você poderia editar a pergunta para deixar mais claro o que você está tentando fazer, e onde está tendo problemas? Fica mais fácil conseguir uma resposta precisa se o problema estiver claro.

Comment: Acho que eu entendi... ele quer exibir várias combos, com os mesmos valores listados, sendo que ao selecionar um valor em qualquer uma delas, o mesmo valor suma das outras combos, de forma que somente uma das combos poderá ter um valor específico por vez.

Comment: Eu irei reformular a pergunta.... mas é exatamente o que o Miguel Angelo falou....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você tenha três combos no seu form com os nomes de `comboBox1`, `comboBox2`, `comboBox3`. Veja se o código abaixo te atende.
Repare que no exemplo eu não utilizo o `DataSource` dos combos e por isso eu tenho a liberdade de alterar os seus `Items`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<ComboBox> _combos;
    private List<string> _originalSource = new List<string> { "um", "dois", "três", "quatro", "cinco" };
    private List<object> _selectedItems = new List<object>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeCombos();
    }

    private void InitializeCombos()
    {
        _combos = new List<ComboBox> { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };
        _combos.ForEach(combo =>
        {
            _originalSource.ForEach(item => combo.Items.Add(item));
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += RemoveOptionFromCombo;
        });
    }

    private void RemoveOptionFromCombo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        _selectedItems = new List<object> 
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedItem, comboBox2.SelectedItem, comboBox3.SelectedItem
        };

        _combos.ForEach(combo =>
        {
            _originalSource.ForEach(item =>
            {
                if (!combo.Items.Contains(item) && !_selectedItems.Contains(item))
                    combo.Items.Add(item);
                if (combo.Items.Contains(item) && _selectedItems.Contains(item) && !item.Equals(combo.SelectedItem))
                    combo.Items.Remove(item);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é definindo os valores que você precisa em um array e fazer um laço de repetição que preencha as combobox.

Feito isso você pode fazer com que no evento [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ele:

- Limpe as outras combobox usando ComboBox.Items.Clear() - ou somente
  onde está duplicado conforme a sua necessidade.
- Execute um novo laço de repetição para preencher as combobox que
  teste e não inclua o item já selecionado.